# android studio attributes layout margin greed disappear from the right upper corner

Tags: android-studio, layout, attributes, android-constraintlayout

When I press a button widget there was always a greed like this image:

[image: screenshot]

I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't align your button component in your layout. You have to align your button position top, bottom, start, end. & then try to click and see.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer, can you explain how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the *.xml, i missed `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` instead I wrote `ReleativeConstraint`.

Thanks